# Sheaf on complete intersections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $Y$ is a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ of codimension $r$, $Y=H_{1} \cap \dots \cap H_{r}$, where $H_{i}$'s are hypersurfaces of degree $d$. Let $Z=H_{1} \cap \dots \cap H_{r-1}$.

Why there exists the short exact sequence: $0 \to \mathcal{O}_{Z}(n-d) \to \mathcal{O}_{Z}(n) \to \mathcal{O}_{Y}(n) \to 0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closed embedding $Y \hookrightarrow Z$ induces a surjective map on sheaves $\mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y$, whose kernel is precisely the set of regular functions on $Z$ vanishing on $Z\cap H_r$, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_{Z}(-d)$.
So we have an exact sequence 
$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z(-d) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow 0$$
We can tensor this with $\mathcal{O}_Z(n)$ and it will stay exact since it locally stays exact because $\mathcal{O}_Z(n)$ is invertible.

Comment: Could you explain why the set of regular functions on $Z$ vanishing on $Z∩H_{r}$ is $\mathcal{O}(-d)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_Z(-d)$ is by definition the pullback of the inclusion $i: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}^n}(-d)$ where this last sheaf can be realized as the set regular functions on $\mathcal{P}^n$ vanishing on $H_r$, since $H_r$ has degree $d$. Thinking carefully about this pullback gives the desired interpretation that's required here.